# How to indicate that code needs to be removed... eventually

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, backwards-compatibility

Consider an app that needs to be compatible with iOS 5 and iOS 6.

Is there a way to mark the code that is there purely for iOS 5 compatibility, so that it appear as a compile error (or warning) when -eventually- the deployment target changes to iOS 6?

Something like this:

```
#IF_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_BIGGER_THAN_IOS_5 
#OUTPUT_ERROR_MESSAGE
#ENDIF
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

If not, what is the best alternative?

Comment: Are you not looking for "deprecated", to mean "This will not be supported in a future release but works ok for now". On method signatures you can use: `DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE`

Comment: Not exactly. Deprecation will output a warning while the legacy code is still necessary, and this has the undesired effect of filling the output with warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 60000
#warning This pre-6.0 code isn't needed anymore
#endif
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

This code will cause a compiler warning once the Deployment Target is set to 6.0 or later.

Answer (score 1):

`#define MY_CONDITIONAL_DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE __deprecated`

use it on all methods BUT until you need it turn it quiet

`#define MY_CONDITIONAL_DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE`

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at how Apple marks that sort of thing in their framework classes. It seems they're making use of the `Availability.h` and `AvailabilityInternal.h` classes in the SDK.